# Jquery - update textbox before submit form2

Tags: jquery

I am running into a weird issue.  What I try to do is update a new query string in the textbox (will change to hidden after it is working), and then submit the form2.

Here is my two input text boxes inside the form with id="form2"

```
<input type="text" size="100" name="sqlCondStr" id="sqlCondStr" value="<%=sql_CondStr%>"/>
<input type="text" size="100" name="sqlCondStrNew" id="sqlCondStrNew" value=""/>
```

my jquery is capturing the new selected ID in the select box and update the "sqlCondStrNew" textbox successfully, but when I have "$("#form2").submit();" submit, it lost the updated value in "sqlCondStrNew" texbbox.

```
$("#SalesRep").on("change", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    sqlCondStr = $("#sqlCondStr").val()
    SalesRepID = $("#SalesRep option:selected").val();
    alert("SalesRepID: " + SalesRepID)

    var sqlCondStrNew = sqlCondStr.replace(/TECH_ID IN \([\d, -]*\)/,"TECH_ID IN (" + SalesRepID + ")");
    alert(sqlCondStrNew);

    $('#sqlCondStrNew').attr("sqlCondStrNew", sqlCondStrNew);
    $("#form2").submit();

});
```

Please help.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're setting an `attr` of `#sqlConStrNew`, not the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what this line means or what you want to do

```
var sqlCondStrNew = sqlCondStr.replace(/TECH_ID IN \([\d, -]*\)/,"TECH_ID IN (" + SalesRepID + ")");
```

but if you want to replace the value of `sqlCondStr` then you should do

```
var sqlCondStrNew = sqlCondStr.val(SalesRepID);
```

and then to store it into `$('#sqlCondStrNew')` change

```
$('#sqlCondStrNew').attr("sqlCondStrNew", sqlCondStrNew);
```

with

```
$('#sqlCondStrNew').val(sqlCondStrNew);
```

Answer (score 1):

i'm not sure what the intention is behind this line..

`$('#sqlCondStrNew').attr("sqlCondStrNew", sqlCondStrNew);`

but you probably wanted to do this instead..

`$('#sqlCondStrNew').val(sqlCondStrNew);`